# SOLID and mapping a collection of DTOs

Tags: c#, mapping, solid-principles

I want to implement mapping from DTOs to view models in C#. The scenario:

- I have a `List<DTO>` and need to map it to `List<ViewModel>`
- The input list contains instances of various classes derived from `DTO`, e.g. `User`, `Product`
- I the result I need different model instance depending on DTO e.g. `UserModel`, `ProductModel` (all derived from `ViewModel`)

My constraints are:

- I cannot use mappers (Automapper, ValueInjecter, ...)
- DTOs are placed in own library and are unaware of the view models (but view models are aware of DTOs)
- I want to be as close to SOLID as possible (I want to avoid switch/if statements based on object types)

Now I am looking for a nice way to implement the whole thing. What I have come up with so far is to create a helper class holding a `Dictionary<Type, Type>` so I could look up which view model to instantiate based on type of DTO (using Activator), Then implement a `ViewModel.Map(DTO dto)` in base view model, then override it in all view model classes. This `Map` method would need to cast the DTO to proper type (e.g. `User` in case of `UserModel.Map()`). Any other suggestions? Can I avoid casting somehow?

**EDIT**

Sample code: https://github.com/andy250/Sandbox (project SmartMap)

Comment: You may find some useful ideas in http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper

Comment: Unfortunately the article does not solve my problem. I have found this: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2013/01/Picking-Overloaded-Methods-at-Runtime.aspx. But again I don't see a way to take advantage of this multiple dispatch in my case.

Comment: Did you checkout the answer? @andy250

Answer (score 0):

You can go with having a class for  containing the object of `Dictionary<Type,Type> map`  better way will be to map DTO class and corresponding Model object, so that `map.get(DTO.class)` gives you the object itself. Like

`Dictionary<class,Model> map;
 map.put(User.class, new UserModel());`

Otherwise , you can have Type mapping using class names and inside the ObjectFactory class create object using reflection.

You can also implement prototype pattern and hence have corresponding class have a static method to return its own object , but singleton and prototype patterns have been known to viopate abstraction

Answer (score 0):

I had reviewed your solution and spent some time to play around options following your requirement. This is how I came to the in order to do what you want you will need to replicate [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) functionality with some Castle Windsor integration. Example discussion how to integrate both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719725/inject-automapper).

This is I am suggesting using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own mapper implementation for each DTO/ViewModel pair based on an interface

```
interface Mapper<TSource,TTarget> {
   TTarget ConvertToTarget(TSource source);
   TSource ConvertFromTarget(TTarget target);
}
```